# How to add an input field on the index page in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am working on a project in yii2. I need to place an `input field` on the `index` page. This field should be similar to the form field. i.e. the type of the field that is used in the form while creating a record. For this, I have done the following

```
 public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = MdcmetercustRel::className();// this is the class whose data field I want to get
    $searchModel = new MdcmetersdataSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,

    ]);
}
```

**My index**

```
 <?=

  $form = ActiveForm::begin();
  $relModel=$model->getModels()[0]; print_r($relModel['cust_id']);
   $form->field($relModel, 'cust_id')->textInput()


  ?>
```

When I refresh my page I am getting

> Object of class yii\widgets\ActiveForm could not be converted to string

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is `<?=`which is trying to output the whole script and you cant echo `$form` or `ActiveForm::begin()`

change it to

```
<?php 

  $form = ActiveForm::begin();
  $relModel=$model->getModels()[0]; print_r($relModel['cust_id']);
  echo $form->field($relModel, 'cust_id')->textInput()
?>
```

Also you need to change the

```
$model = MdcmetercustRel::className();
```

to

```
$model = new MdcmetercustRel();
```

otherwise there wont be an object in `$model` but a string i.e class namespace.

Comment: now I am getting `Call to a member function getModels() on string`

Comment: that is a separate issue which has no link with the question asked, the mentioned problem is removed by using the suggested answer, about the error, it means `$model` is not an object you should check what is inside the `$model` @Faisal

Comment: Should I post another question ?

Comment: But I have some data in the table

Comment: dude you are confused if you are trying to access data then use the `ModelName::find()` otherwise create a new object @Faisal

Comment: @Faisal this is a separate issue you should add a separate question for it , the original exception has been solved